# Topology: continuity

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

I am not sure how to approach the question.

Let $X=\{a,b\}$ and define two topological spaces on $X$ by

- $\tau_1=\{\emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$
- $\tau_2=\{\emptyset, \{b\}, X\}$

Is a function given by $f:(X, \tau_1) \rightarrow (X, \tau_2)$ defined by $f(x)=x$ continuous?

Should approach it by to cases $f(a)=a$, $f(b)=b$?

Comment: Hint: check if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open set (only 3 sets in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only open sets in $\tau_2$ are $\emptyset$, $\{b\}$, and $X$. Notice that $f^{-1}(\{b\})=\{b\}$, which is not open in $\tau_1$, so $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: You should write $f^{-1}\{b\} =\{b\}$.

Comment: So i say that by definition, f is continuous on $b \in X$ if for every neighborhood N of f(b), the set $f^{-1}(N)$ is a neighborhood of b. But $f^{-1}{b}={b}$ which is not an open set in $\tau_1$, hence not a neighborhood?

Comment: @universekid8 He uses $f$ is continuous iff for all open subsets $O$ of the codomain we have that $f^{-}[O]$ is open in the domain.